# How to describe the leakage of rain from a house roof

Tags: verbs, adjectives

How to describe the leakage of rain from a house roof? Such as the house leaks, rain drips from the roof, the house is not waterproof,or it is leaking? Thank you very much!

Comment: In addition to StonyB’s great answer note the “the roof” is outside, and “the ceiling” is inside: The roof leaks and water drips from the ceiling or sometimes when the roof leaks, the water stays inside the ceiling and runs down inside the walls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally we say "The roof leaks".

"Rain drips from the roof" would usually describe rain dripping outside the house, from the eaves.

"The house leaks" might be used to say that water regularly enters the house from a source other than the roof—from groundwater, for instance—but we would be more likely to mention where the water enters: "The basement leaks" or "The walls leak", for instance. It might also be used to say that something leaks *out* of the house: heated air in the winter, for instance. "The house is leaking" has the same meanings, but indicates that it is happening right now.

"The house is not waterproof" means that the house cannot keep water out.

Comment: +2. I will give superuser the benefit of my own bad luck and add that one is likely to infer from "The roof leaks" that the house has multiple leaks. The phrase "The house has a leaky roof" implies there are leaks in several places. If you wanted to point out that water is getting through in a particular place that requires repair, you could say "There's a leak in the roof" or "The roof has a leak".